# logistic map with lamba greater than 4

Tags: mathematical-modeling, chaos-theory, iterated-function-system

I was doing some recreational math about the logistic map. (If you're not familiar with what the logistic map is, here are some links you can check out)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ETrYE4MdoLQ

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map

I have seen pictures that show the convergence of populations with different values of r (or lambda) and have observed the bifurcation behavior. However, of all the maps I have seen, none of them include the effects with an r value greater than 4. Why is this? And can anyone provide a map like this? I'm really curious to see what happens.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much but [this paper](http://chrome-extension://oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm/https://www.degruyter.com/downloadpdf/j/zna.1997.52.issue-6-7/zna-1997-6-708/zna-1997-6-708.pdf) says that the logistic map diverges if the parameter is greater than 4 (or less than -2).